# How do I delete pictures that I've chosen as favorite?

Tags: lumia-520, photos, system-apps

I have chosen some pictures as favorite. How do I delete those?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean deleting the photos altogether, or removing the favourite status from them? What have you tried so far?